# The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit of a linear vs a non linear function

Tags: limits, education, epsilon-delta

I am teaching elementary analysis and introducing the concept of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit to first time learners. For example, we take $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 2} (2x - 1) = 3$, then we say by definition:

For every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $|2x-1-3|<\epsilon$.

We can go on and say that $|2x-4| = 2|x-2| < \epsilon$. From which we can see that: $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Hence, we can choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Now all this seems very very abstract to a first time learner, and so I always supplement with a table of values (which is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$, but not too obvious to the first learner.)

For example:

\begin{array}{ccc}
x &1.8 & 1.9 & 2 & 2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3  \\
y & 2.6 & 2.8 & \# & 3.2 & 3.4 & 3.6 
\end{array}

I intentionally blocked off $y=3$ to argue that the function need not be defined at that point for the limit to exist. Of course, we can always just put 3 for simplicity. Finally, we see that for every $0.1$ increment in $x$, there is a $0.2$ increment in $y$. OR, you can say for every $0.2$ increment in $x$, there is a corresponding change of $0.4$ in $y$. (and other analogies.) Hence, learners can easily see the $\epsilon/2$ in the ratios of these increments, and everyone is happy.

Now, my question is, I want to extend this heuristic when I teach the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition now, for functions that are non-linear. Say, $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 - 1 = 3$. I am lost. (and perhaps, became a victim of myself trying to make this simpler.)

Any insights?

Comment: Using (elementary) inequalities always helps. The $\delta$ need not to be the smallest for the given $\epsilon$ -- as long as it can prove the problem, it is then good enough.

Comment: You may want to look at the following answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1333329/72031

Comment: I like your idea! How difficult are the limit problems you'll be teaching your class? If you don't go past basic polynomials, you could factor $x^2-4$ as $(x-2)(x+2)$ and hence "create" the linear piece $x-2$ for your described method. Then you could add something about how to handle the $x+2$ part. If you get into limits involving things like $\ln(x), \sin(x), e^x$ etc. I don't know that this "linear" method will work. Although no matter what, I think you could explain to your class that the "linear" examples are only a stepping stone to get the idea of finding $\delta$.

Comment: Well, i think i will do some $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions until polynomials only. It would be insanely difficult to try transcendental functions with this definition, perhaps.