# How to verify limits

Tags: limits

From the uploaded image, I fail to understand why the correct (or permissible) value for delta is the minimum among the two values. Why or how is the minimum value the correct one, why not the other way around? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "the other way around"?

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354988/proving-continuity-of-fx-x2/2355006#2355006

Comment: You need to find *one* value of $\delta$ that forces $|x^2 - 4|$ to be small enough.  There are some cases in which $2 - \sqrt{4-\varepsilon}$ is required, and other cases in which $\sqrt{4+\varepsilon} - 2$ is required.  If $|x-2|$ is smaller than only one of those, we might not get what we want; but if it is smaller than *both*, then we are in business.  Hence we take the minimum.

Comment: First of all the book's solution is wrong (because of a circular argument which is difficult to detect). Next the way it has been presented is worse. The same symbol $\delta$ has been used to denote two different quantities. Also such a solution is bound to confuse readers and your question is a perfect outcome of studying this solution. I refer you to a similar example for more information: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2349196/72031 Another answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1333329/72031) may also be helpful.